# Reverse an array containing random numbers. How?

Tags: c#, arrays, random, reverse

My assignment is to create an array with random numbers and then reverse the order in C#.

I managed to generate the random array, but **how do i reverse it?**

For example the output should look like this

15334
43351

```
int[] TalArray = new int[5];
var arr = new int[TalArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < TalArray.Length; i++)

{
    Random random = new Random();
    int num = random.Next(TalArray.Length);

    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-6.0? Also, you shouldn't be creating a new random inside of your loop. Create an instance of random outside the loop and use it within the loop.

Comment: The example output doesn't seem to be random, or do you mean you're just going to sort them in ascending order then reverse that sorted array?

Comment: @Martheen Thanks for your input! 
Sorry my bad! I have edited my example output. 
I need to generate random numbers and output them. Then I need to reverse my output. So let's say the random generated numbers are 15334 then my reverse order should be 43351.

Comment: @Anu6is Thanks for your input! 

Hmm would you mind showing me how I can do that? 

As far as I can see, my loop only insert random numbers to each place in the array.

Comment: @Jesper I notice that you created two arrays: `TalArray` and `arr`. Is the intention to put the reverse of `TalArray` into `arr`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for your input. It's crazy how helpful all of you are. I found a solution to my question. My intention was to generate an random array and reverse it. `TalArray` or `arr`, it didn't really matter in this case (I think). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with Array.Reverse:

```
var arr = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
  {
     arr[i] = new Random().Next(0, arr.Length);
  }
var revArr = arr.Reverse();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", arr ) + string.Join("", revArr));
```

Comment: Wauw thank you so much @steko! I didn't know about the String.Join. Brilliant!

Comment: String.Join is very useful if you want to print collection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-6.0)

```cs
public static void Main()
    {
        int[] TalArray = new int[5];
        var arr = new int[TalArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < TalArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int num = random.Next(TalArray.Length);
            arr[i] = num;
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        } 
        
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        } 
    }
```

Working example [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G8L8A3)

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That was excatly what i needed. As you can tell, I'm very new, so I really appreciate your input. Have a great day Martin :)